# javax.sound.midi.Sequencer's isRunning() returns false even though it should be running

Tags: java, midi

I have an open MIDI Sequencer that plays Sequences in a special playFile method.

```
private void playFile (String filepath) {
    try {
        sequencer.setSequence(new FileInputStream(filepath));
        sequencer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

Since I want to play several files in a certain order I am calling playFile from elsewhere and waiting for the Sequencer to complete before sending the next one.

```
// ... (iterating through the files to be played)
playFile(currentFile.getPath);
currentFile.setPlaying(true);
while (sequencer.isRunning()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

This works alright.

Now, to make sure there is no audible gap between the files playing (each less than a second long) I tried reducing the sleep time to 10 and started encountering problems. The lower the amount of milliseconds to wait gets, the more prone the program becomes to "skip" files - they don't appear to be played at all. At least I don't hear them, instead the next or an even later one follows.

Adding a System.out.println() inside the while-loop showed that even for the "skipped" files the loop is actually entered at least once - the Sequencer must be running in that case. However, after a few milliseconds without audible output isRunning() suddenly returns false and the program exits the while-loop, continuing with the next file. It usually looks pretty much like this:

> ...
>   sequencer is running: true (current file: Takt22.mid)
>   sequencer is running: true (current file: Takt22.mid)
>   sequencer is running: true (current file: Takt22.mid)
>   sequencer is running: false (current file: Takt22.mid)
>   sequencer is running: false (current file: Takt128.mid)
>   sequencer is running: true (current file: Takt63.mid)
>   sequencer is running: true (current file: Takt63.mid)
>   ...

In this case Takt128.mid is not played and Takt63.mid becomes active right after Takt22.mid. However, as while has been entered once, the Sequencer must have been running with file Takt128.mid at least for a short moment (less than 10 milliseconds, for the output happens after a Thread.sleep of that time).

All the files are ok, I both checked them and made sure this bug is not dependent on specific files but can happen to any of them. For all it's worth it LOOKS like the Sequencer would just return to be not running sometimes, without apparent reason.